# Regex matching the entire string and nothing else

Tags: c#, regex

I'm am trying to match the string `TF8/Z2IF` using regex. I only want to match that string and nothing else. I am having issues at the moment where other similar strings  `TF8/Z2IFPP`or `1TF8/Z2IF` are being matched. Could someone please show me how to match only `TF8/Z2IF`?

Comment: Use start and end markers: `^TF8/Z2IF$`.  But better yet, why not just use C# string equality, if you want an exact match?

Comment: Using regex is also going to be considerably slower than direct string comparison in c#

Comment: So why does that not work when testing. If it try that ^$ on this site it doesn't work https://regexr.com/

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what isn't working on regexr- saved you failed attempt and post  direct link to it. We can't do anything with "I tried what you said and it didn't work" - but I'd err on the side of "you probably misunderstood or weren't able to implement what we said" (because if we'd made a mistake one of us would have corrected us by now )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably forgot to put `^` at the start of the pattern and `$` at the end of it..

..but if you're searching for an exact string, just use `==` or `.Equals` - regex is an unnecessary performance hit.

If you mean that you have a document full of words and you want "whole word" style searching, use `\b` before and after the pattern:

```
var input = "This is a test that is testing latest regex attempts";
var r = new Regex(@"\btest\b");
r.IsMatch(input); //true

input = "Now I attest we're testing non whole word tests";
r.IsMatch(input); //false
```

The `\b` means "word boundary" and is conceptually things like "start of input", "whitespace", "punctuation" etc so putting at the start and end of "test" means that if the document contains "test" it matches but it doesn't match "attest" or "testing"

Comment: @arne use of `var` in C# is syntactically valid and encouraged where the variable type can be easily deduced from the right side of the assignment